# Use .htaccess to Redirect URL excluding image folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mysqli, php-7

My **public_html** looks like following →

**1. /image/ [ DIRECTORY]**

**2. /scripts/ [DIRECTORY]**

**3. index.php [FILE]**

**4. Logo.jpg**

**Other files also exists like php.ini, error_log** .,etc.

I want `example.com/`**seo-url** to get searched from my database table **url_alis** for which I have the code written under **scripts/get_url_info.php** to fetch and output the data

But any other file like

> **ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css**

under **image** and **style**(for css) folder should not get processed under this rule

I have tried a lot but either of below issues persist

1. The images and other files also get processed under this rule, which returns the URL text I use to check the functionality of **get_url_info.php** (Ex. query, file name , etc)
2. The redirect gets processed with **.php** extension followed by the **seo-url** (apple-mangoes.php), which returns of **404**
3. If `mysqli_num_rows == 0` in the **db→url_alias** table from query in **script/get_url_info.php** , the URL should point to example.com which is not happening.

My Current .htaccess file (apologies for the un-harmonized code)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule    ^([^?]*)    scripts/get_url_info.php?url=$1    [L,QSA]    # Process all products
RewriteRule    ^/image/([^?]*)    /image/$1/$2    [L,QSA]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The basic requirement here is , if the url points to a text only (with symbols like (_,-,%,&) **REQUEST_URI** request, **without** a **/ forward slash** or **without** a folder which has display content, it should go to my **get_url_info.php** script otherwise normally process all content.

Other Important Pre-Requisites -

- Force HTTPS
- Force www
- Redirect to index.php if invalid URL or content not found

Answer (score 0):

First to answer your pre-requisites, use the code below in your .HTACCESS file.

Force HTTPS:

```
### HTTP to HTTPS ###
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

---

Force www:

```
### Redirect from non-www to www version ###
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

---

Redirect to index.php if invalid URL or content not found:

For 404 Error use the below code

```
### Custom Error Pages  ###
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 /html/404-error.html
```

as you want to redirect them to home page, you can use

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```